# Office 365 graph api /sites/search does not return all sites

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm seeing inconsistent behavior with the graph api /sites?search= call.

Here is an example:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=

{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites",
    "value": [
        {
            "createdDateTime": "2017-09-15T10:53:07Z",
            "id": "fake.sharepoint.com,67f79958-537d-4611-85b1-9e24c53db8e8,82dc47eb-9ab0-40eb-9ad6-49bb62983710",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-09-15T10:57:26Z",
            "name": "companydrive",
            "webUrl": "https://fake.sharepoint.com/sites/Fake/companydrive",
            "displayName": "Company Drive"
        }
    ]
}
```

client request id - afbfb651-8776-4561-a554-5777ff3ecf07

This appears incorrect as I can see other sites:

[image: admin console]

I can try to reference a site directly:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/fake.sharepoint.com/:/
```

Which does actually return a result:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites/$entity",
    "createdDateTime": "2017-09-10T18:55:05.853Z",
    "description": "",
    "id": "fake.sharepoint.com,c814fb30-d5f8-40ad-acf5-2cb270b27723,d9ced640-50f8-49b7-b138-41bc4469edf3",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-03-07T16:32:48Z",
    "name": "",
    "webUrl": "https://fake.sharepoint.com",
    "root": {},
    "siteCollection": {
        "hostname": "fake.sharepoint.com"
    },
    "displayName": "Fake Limited Team Site"
}
```

It looks to me like the sites?search= call is not returning the correct list of sites.    Is this a bug?

Comment: Any update on this subject ? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling a SharePoint site using a beta endpoint for the Graph API. I recommend using v1.0:

```
GET /sites/{site-id}/drive/root/search(q='{search-text}')
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-search?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http